# Search a comma separated value using Entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have the following string **3,9** where I want to search it's 2 values (3 and 9) inside a database table that looks like follow

[image]

so if my string would contain only the number 3 my query should return all 5 rows, if I sent the number 9 it should return only 2 rows and if I send 3,9 it also should return all 5 rows

I am having trouble writing the code in my class

```
var t = GetAll()
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ApproversId))
        {
            List<string> ApproversIdL = ApproversId.Split(',').ToList();
            // this is where i am having trouble
            t = t.Where(s => s.AproversIds.Any(x=>x.ToString()== ApproversIdL.Any(x=>x.ToString())));                                
        }
```

Appreciate any help

Comment: Is it EntityFramework or EntityFrameworkCore?

Comment: it is entity framework Core

Comment: EF is an ORM, so the real answer would be to use a relational schema, in this case a many-to-many mapping. I.e. if this is a Submissions table where a submission can have many approvers, and an approver is linked to many submissions, having a SubmissionApprovers table. From that you can perform these filter checks at the database level rather than loading all data first into memory.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `t = GetAll()` is a list with rows.

So you have to split each `t.AproversIds` column value the same way as you had splitted the `ApproversId` parameter and check is there any intersection

```
var ApproversIdL = ApproversId.Split(',');
t = t.Where(s => s.AproversIds.Split(',').Any(p => ApproversIdL.Contains(p) ));
```

Comment: I tried it but this 's.AproversIds.Split(',')' is giving an error saying: an expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments

Comment: There seems to be a typo in the response. Try:
           `var approversIdL = approversId.Split(",");
            var matchingList = t.Where(x => x.Split(",").Any(p => approversIdL.Contains(p)));`

Comment: No it is the same issue

Comment: @lzydrmr it is becuase `GetAll()`  returns `IQueryable<>` as I understood now and local variables are not enabled. @Sora I'm afraid that you can try to solve it by stored procedure with input parameter whatever. Or it should be solved using `plain T-SQL approach` without c# variables references

Comment: @oleksa thanks for the clarification. Alternatively, you could convert the `IQueryable<>` to a `List<>` (by calling `ToList()`). However, in a production setting this might not be wise regarding performance.

Answer (score 0):

I was beating around the bushes on how can we search for multiple values and came up with this. :P

```
Dictionary<int, string> data = new Dictionary<int, string>();
data.Add(1, "3,97");
data.Add(2, "9,3");
data.Add(3, "3");
data.Add(4, "3");
data.Add(5, "3,4");

//search string with comma separated value
string searchItems = "9";
var tempSearchItems = searchItems;

searchItems = searchItems.Replace(",", "|").Replace(" ", "");

//Pattern for the regex
string pattern = @"\b(" + searchItems + @")\b";

//get the result
var test = data.Where(d => Regex.Matches(d.Value, pattern).Count > 0).ToList();
```

Let me know if it helps

Comment: This might work in this special example, but will lead to trouble if the search items contain characters that are interpreted by the regex engine (e.g. an asterisk).

Comment: the problem is that the question is about EntityFramework, and `GetAll` returns `IQueryable<>` (not `IEnumerable<>`). Then it is appended with `Where` and is translated to the SQL. There is no data in the program memory actually until you are starting to enumerate the `GetAll()` result

Comment: That is an interesting scenario. Won't the Split actually call the data in memory? Doesnt that mean the query is already been executed when split is in action? Also, Contains will give a false match if the data contains double digit number and search string contains single digit.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL Server then you can use the [SqlMethods.Like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.like.aspx) to filter the database result set down to a manageable subset of data that can then be extract items in memory with RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working demo that you could refer to

```
 public async Task<IActionResult>  Test()
    {
        var ApproversId = "3,9";
        var t = (from a in _context.Answers
                select a).ToList();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ApproversId))
        {
            List<string> ApproversIdL = ApproversId.Split(',').ToList();
            t = t.Where(s => ApproversIdL.Any(al=>s.AproversIds.Contains(al))).ToList();

        }
        return View();
    }
```

Result:
[image]